# Is it OK to use SyncOrchestrator in Hub-Spoke architecture?

Tags: ado.net, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

After far too much time researching the Microsoft Sync Framework, and associated technologies, I still am not sure of the answer to this...Can I use the SyncOrchestrator functionality in a Hub-Spoke architecture. Basically, am writing a client that must be able to operate in a "disconnected" mode so, it will need to maintain a local data store, and sync to a central database (no peer-to-peer syncing will occur). So, is SyncOrchestrator appropriate for this? It seems much easier to use that SyncAgent on the client application but, I am not sure if I am using it correctly.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give. There are so many technologies, and versions of technologies, from Microsoft in this area that, my head is spinning a bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use the syncorchestrator in either hub-spoke or peer-to-peer scenario. the newer sync providers used by syncorchestrator allows you the flexibility of moving your hub database without having to reinitialize your sync community and also provides much better performance when using bulk operations.

Comment: JuneT. Thank you so much for the clarification! I have really been confused by the two approaches (Sync Services vs Syn Framework), and all the issues that must be considered when comparing them. But, in many cases, I have found your responses in this forum and others, and your blog posts to be very helpful. Thank you so much for your clarification.

Comment: the Sync Services/SyncAgent is the first generation of database providers (the same one used by the VS Local Database Cache wizard and the only one supported on WM devices)... the SyncOrchestrator is a newer provider (unfortunately, no VS tooling support unless you use the SQL Compact Toolbox where we built support for the newer provider)